# word embeddings with BioGpt

Tags: huggingface-tokenizers

I need help to generate word embeddings and store them in a column of a pandas DataFrame.
What should I do?

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

from transformers import BioGptTokenizer

with open("data.json") as input_data:
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(json.load(input_data))

bio_tokenizer = BioGptTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/biogpt")

df["embedding"] = df["content"].apply(lambda x: <what to do here?>)
```

what is the lambda function that I need ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from transformers import BioGptTokenizer, BioGptModel

def get_embedding(sentence, model, tokenizer):
  inputs = tokenizer(sentence, return_tensors="pt")
  outputs = model(**inputs)
  embedding = outputs.last_hidden_state
  return embedding

with open("data.json") as input_data:
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(json.load(input_data))

bio_tokenizer = BioGptTokenizer.from_pretrained("microsoft/biogpt")
model = BioGptModel.from_pretrained("microsoft/biogpt")

df["embedding"] = df["content"].apply(lambda x: get_embedding(x, model, bio_tokenizer))
```

Remember that if you are storing the embedding in a dataframe, pandas will convert the datatype of the embedding from tensor to object. So you will need to change the datatype before use.